# IE 11 doesn't update selected Option Item label within Select Element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

**What's I'm Trying To Do**

Dynamically change the label of the selected *option element* within a *select element* on IE 11.

**What I'm Expecting**

As the label of the selected *option element* is being changed, the text shown on the *select element* changes as well.

**What is Actually Happening**

IE 11 ignores the fact that the *option element*'s label is being changed. The selected *option element* and corresponding text displayed on the *select element* will not change until the *select element* is selected again.

See the code below:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option id="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option id="option2">Option 2</option>
            <option id="option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <input id="field1" oninput="setLabel()" \>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function setLabel() {
    var text = document.getElementById("field1").value;
    document.getElementById("option1").label = text;
}
```

So, keeping the *select element* on `Option 1`, enter text into the *input field*. The *option element* won't update it's text until the *select element* is selected.

It works as expected in Chrome. Any idea on how to hack or alert IE11 of the update?

Comment: Although not urgent at this point (for me), an all-around solution (if existent) would be useful. (still looking for answers)

Answer (score 0):

Tested in IE11 - not an emulator. Wow... This is this hacky, but I think it does what you need. The console log call and multiple changes away from and back to the selected option were necessary for the rerendering. Anything less and the label was sometimes a keystroke or two behind.

```js
function setLabel() {
  let inputText = document.getElementById("field1").value,
    selectField = document.getElementById("select1");

  selectField.value = "2";
  document.getElementById("option1").label = inputText;
  console.log(inputText);
  selectField.value = "1";
  selectField.value = "2";
  selectField.value = "1";
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
            <option id="option1" value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option id="option2" value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option id="option3" value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
<input id="field1" oninput="setLabel()" \>
```

Comment: This is consistently delayed, or behind, for me. Me typing "1" "2" "3" "4" shows up as "" "12" "12" "1234". Very close though! I'm gonna experiment a bit more. Every second character is triggering the re-render.

Comment: That's frustrating, I saw that too but then it was okay after adding some garbage code. I know how bad this sounds, but did you try adding even more "unnecessary" calls to toggle options or more console log entries to try to give the render engine time to catch up?

Comment: Just to clarify - This is not a good way to code. My production team solution would be to use the select2, selectize, jqueryui, or a custom solution that is an input and a list styled to look and act like a select - or forget IE altogether if acceptable based on client traffic analytic data. *disclaimer over

Comment: At this point I'm forgetting IE altogether. I think that your solution would work depending on how fast (or slow, rather) the client's machine works. Making custom made select elements is in the low priority features at this point, since the items shown are shown differently depending on the OS (can't reliably style them). I ended up running into other problems with IE11, so Edge is minimum at this point. Thanks though!

Comment: You bet. You should consider closing this question since there was no real solution.